# Finite subcover of an explicit open cover of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Given the set $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$

Let
$$O=\{(a-0.1,a+0.1) | a \in [0,1]\}$$
be an infinite open cover of $[0,1]$. Because $O$ is finite, I cannot see *any* example of finite subcover of $O$, since each interval of this subcover must be contained in $(a-0.1,a+0.1)$ for every $a$ in $[0,1]$.

Please, could anybody show me an example of finite subcover of the infinite open cover $O$ that still covers $[0,1]$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When you wrote that **O** is finite, perhaps that you meant otherwise.

Comment: Just when you say $O$ is inifinite, the next line you claim that $O$ is finite?

Answer (score 1):

Take$$\left\{\left(a-\frac1{10},a+\frac1{10}\right)\,\middle|\,a\in\left\{0,\frac1{10},\frac2{10},\frac3{10},\ldots,1\right\}\right\}.$$It is a subset of $O$, it is finite, and it is an open cover of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $n$ such that $\frac  2 n <0.1$. Then the intervals $(\frac i n-0.1, \frac i n +0.1)$ with $0 \leq i \leq n$ cover $[0,1]$.

Proof: For any $x$ there exists $i$ such that $\frac {i-1} n \leq x <\frac i n$. This gives $|x- \frac i n| \leq \frac 1 n <\frac 2 n<0.1$.